# Access: "The LinkMasterFields property setting has produced this error: 'The object doesn't contain the Automation object 'TableOne."

Tags: ms-access

I have a form with a subform.

In the form, there are data of `TableOne` for a certain `TableOne.ID = [Number manually entered].`

In the subform, there are data of `TableTwo` where `TableOne.ID = TableTwo.ID.` The relationship is well built.

In main form -> `Property Sheet` -> `Data`, I have:

- Link Master Fields: `TableOne.ID`
- Link Child Fields: `ID`

Despite of this, I get the following message when I am trying to enter data in the subform:

```
"The LinkMasterFields property setting has produced this error: 'The object doesn't contain the Automation object 'TableOne."
```

According to me, there is some error in the `Record Source`:

- In the main form, the `Record Source` is the selection of all data
  of `TableOne` when `TableOne.ID = [Form]![ID entered by the user]`.
- In the subform, the `Record Source` is the selection of all data of `TableTwo`.

I don't know if I have to put `TableTwo` in the `Record Source` of the main form, or `TableOne.ID` in the subform, or what.

**SOLVED**

In the `Record Source` of the main form, I had also the table `TableThree` that has a field named `ID`. This could make problem with the program. So I have removed `TableThree.ID` from the `Record Source` and changed the name of `TableTwo.ID` to `TableTwo.TID`.

After that, as suggested by *Gustav*, I put:

- Link Master Fields: `ID`
- Link Child Fields: `TID`

Comment: Really should give objects more meaningful names. Main form does not have SourceObject property. Subform container has SourceObject property. Perhaps you meant RecordSource?

Comment: @June7 right, RecordSource. Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use field names only:

Link Master Fields: ID

Also, naming a field in TableTwo holding a *foreign key* as *ID* is a bad idea. Name it *FK* or *TableOneId* or similar.